# error: unexpected EOF when kubectl cp dump.rdb file to local

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kubectl

I have this redis instance in a pod running on 1.21 cluster.

Running `kubectl cp -c redis --request-timeout=1m redis-pod:data/dump.rdb /tmp/data/dump.rdb`

or

`kubectl exec --request-timeout=1m -i redis-pod -- cat /data/dump.rdb > /tmp/data/dump.rdb`

I get the following two errors:

The `kubectl cp` approach generates: `error: unexpected EOF`

The second approach creates the file but incomplete, with a smaller size and when loading it with another redis instance I got a server message like the DB is corrupted and wont start.

I've ran redis `SAVE` command before. Also copied the `dump.rdb` to another directory a tried to copy that one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like the dump is corrupted

Comment: Yes, it gets corrupted at transfer time. I've tried also with a different redis db, and its the same result.

Comment: Hi, I've let the process on hold. But please give me some time to try out your solution. Thanks for your interest

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **kubectl  cp** **--retries=10** if the connection is getting timeout while copying the file.

If you are in **Redis POD** and just want to **take out** the **data** you can install the **aws**, **gcp** **CLI** and upload the whole file from POD to the bucket.

Touching Redis data files is fine, i to have played lot but would recommend checking out the [**Riot-Redis**](https://github.com/redis-developer/riot)

Used it a lot in migrating large production system Redis data from one to another cluster.

Read more about Riot-Redis doc : https://developer.redis.com/riot/riot-redis/

**RIOT-Redis** is a **data** **migration** tool for **Redis**.

> Most Redis migration tools available today are offline in nature.
> Migrating data from AWS ElastiCache to Redis Enterprise Cloud for
> example means backing up your Elasticache data to an AWS S3 bucket and
> importing it into Redis Enterprise Cloud using its UI. RIOT-Redis
> allows for live data migration between any Redis databases.